# Match a list of tags/labels EXACTLY in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement of getting rows that **EXACTLY** match a list of labels or tags. I have a Labels main table, ContentLabels table with Label FK, and a Contents table.

Content Table:
Id, Name, CustomerId

Label table: Id, Text

ContentLabels Table:
ContentId, LabelId

I have a list of labels (any number of labels), i want to match exactly those labels while querying the data from sql. I tried the following solution from SO somewhere:

```
DECLARE @LabelTexts NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'coke,edible,chips';
DECLARE @Labels AS TABLE(
    [Text] NVARCHAR(128)
);
INSERT INTO @Labels ([Text])
SELECT [Data] FROM StrSplit(@LabelTexts, ',')

DECLARE @LabelsCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Labels);

        SELECT  c.[CustomerID] ,
                c.[ContentID] AS Id ,
                c.ClusterId
         FROM ContentLabels cbl
         JOIN Labels l ON l.ClusterId = cbl.LabelClusterId
         JOIN Content c ON c.ClusterId = cbl.ContentClusterId
         GROUP BY c.[CustomerID], 
                c.[ContentID],
                c.ClusterId
        HAVING 
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN l.[Text] IN( 'coke','chips','edible') THEN l.[Text] END)=@LabelsCount
            AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN l.[Text] NOT IN( 'coke','chips','edible') THEN l.[Text] END) = 0;
```

When the above query execues, it works perfectly fine as i have added tags/labels in hard form in the **IN** clause in **Having** clause. But when i added the following query in the HAVING clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN l.[Text] IN(SELECT * FROM @Labels) THEN l.[Text] END)=@LabelsCount
            AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN l.[Text] NOT IN(SELECT * FROM @Labels) THEN l.[Text] END) = 0;
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

And it is just because of

> SELECT * FROM @Labels

in having clause. Its been several hours looking into the solution for it but didn't succeed. Any help would be commendable.

Comment: The above looks like T-SQL, not MySQL, why have you tagged both here? What about the error don't you understand, as it's telling you the problem.

Comment: @Larnu the solution i got is from MySql query which i changed into T-Sql. Yes the error is understandable but i have no idea of its solution. I have tried by concatenating the labels but no success.

Comment: You can't put a subquery inside an aggregate, you need to put it elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, but where that query needs to be added. It is counting the data set, i tried by taking the counts before this query and directly applying in the having clause, it did not work.

Comment: If you replace `SELECT * FROM @Labels` with `SELECT [Data] FROM StrSplit(@LabelTexts, ',')`, what happens? `in(select *...` is wrong anyway, `in(select [Text]...` would more logical.

Comment: @Arvo i have tried this in(select [Text]... as well. Didn't work. Replacing SELECT * FROM Label with query you said, its still a subquery.

Comment: What's the primary key of `Content` table?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Id is GUID but i also have ClusterId which is INT for joins and is the primary key. In the description i have simplified the tables

Answer (score 1):

You need to left join the matches you want, then do conditional aggergation.

This type of query is called "Relational Division Without Remainder", see [Joe Celko](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) et al on this.

```
SELECT  c.[CustomerID] ,
                c.[ContentID] AS Id ,
                c.ClusterId
    FROM ContentLabels cbl
    JOIN Labels l ON l.ClusterId = cbl.LabelClusterId
    JOIN Content c ON c.ClusterId = cbl.ContentClusterId
    LEFT JOIN @labels labelMatches ON labelMatches.[Text] = l.[Text]
    GROUP BY c.[CustomerID], 
        c.[ContentID],
        c.ClusterId
    HAVING 
        COUNT(DISTINCT labelMatches.[Text] END)=@LabelsCount
        AND COUNT(CASE WHEN labelMatches.[Text] IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: that's it. This is working exactly as expected. Giorgos Betsos answer is also working but i'll prefer this left join solution. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Use the operator LIKE:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ',' + @LabelTexts + ',' LIKE '%,' + l.[Text] + ',%' THEN l.[Text] END) = @LabelsCount
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ',' + @LabelTexts + ',' NOT LIKE '%,' + l.[Text] + ',%' THEN l.[Text] END) = 0;
```

Comment: this did not work, it brought the rows that had any of the labels. Not exactly same labels.

Comment: @Harry.Naeem check this simplified case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=622440a366ca45b4d1f31e11d3f48e7f The code should work. Post sample data to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `NOT EXITS` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    c.[CustomerID]
    , c.[ContentID]
    , c.ClusterId
FROM Content c
JOIN ContentLabels cl
JOIN Labels l ON l.ClusterId = cl.LabelClusterId
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    -- to filter out c.ClusterId values being related to labels NOT IN the specified list
    SELECT 1
    FROM ContentLabels cl2
    JOIN Labels l2 ON l2.ClusterId = cl2.LabelClusterId
    WHERE (l2.[Text] NOT IN(SELECT * FROM @Labels)) 
            AND c.ClusterId = cl2.ContentClusterId
)
GROUP BY  
    c.[CustomerID]
    , c.[ContentID]
    , c.ClusterId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l.[Text]) = @LabelsCount
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. It is working as expected.